# Не загружается изображение, которое выбрал пользователь

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

Есть профиль человека, человек может его редактировать, в том числе выбирать изображение, которое будет у него на аватарке.

При редактировании в профиле успешно меняются все что нужно (телефон, почта и т.д.), но выбранное изображение никуда не загружается. То есть если посмотреть код элемента аватарки в профиле, то там будет написано

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
```

Более того, та фотография, которую загружает человек не появляется у меня в файлах самого проекта. Не могу понять, что я делаю не так.

Структура проекта:

```
socialka
|---socialka
|       |---settings.py
|       |---urls.py
|
|---accounts
|       |---views.py
|       |---models.py
|
|---media
      |---profile_image
```

```
socialka/settings.py:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/profile_image/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

```
socialka/urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
               ...
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```
accounts/models.py:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="../media/profile_image", blank=True, null=True)
```

```
accounts/views.py:
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        request.user.userprofile.image = request.POST['image']
        request.user.userprofile.save()
        return redirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        args = {'user': request.user}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

```
account/edit_profile.html:
...
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        ...
        <label for="image">Фото профиля:</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="rounded"><br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Изменить</button>
    </form>
...
```

[Вот ссылка на весь проект](https://github.com/Jimiliani/my_python/tree/master/socialka)

Буду рад любой критике

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**views**

```
request.FILES['image']
```

**template**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```